# Get data from a page with the same form elements

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I have page called account.php
It displays user data from a mysql table.(in this question i will use a mail system as an example)

The account page has the following code in it:

```
while($stmt->fetch()){
    echo "<tr>
    <td>
    <form action='action.php' method='POST'>
        <input type='hidden' name='mail_id' value='$mail_id'>
         Mail:$mail_subject
        <input type='submit' name='reply value='reply'>
        <input type='submit' name='delete' value='delete'>

    <form>
    </td>
    </tr> ";
}
```

where
In action.php I have this code:

```
if(isset($_POST['reply'])){
   echo "$_POST['mail_id']";
} 
if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
   echo "$_POST['mail_id']";
}
```

In the the rendered html. the last mail_id is 101
and when i click the reply button on mail_id '35' the post value  returned is 101.

My question is how can I obtain mail_id '35' when I click the reply button in the mail_id '35' row and not '101'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should move your form tags away from while cycle. And after that you can give your reply and delete button different names like `reply[$mail_id]` and `delete[$mail_id]`. So you can check on backend which one was clicked

```
echo "<form action='action.php' method='POST'>";
while($stmt->fetch()){
    echo"<tr>
    <td>
        <input type='hidden' name='mail_id' value='$mail_id'>
         Mail:$mail_subject
        <input type='submit' name='reply[$mail_id]' value='reply'>
        <input type='submit' name='delete[$mail_id]' value='delete'>
    </td>
    </tr> ";
}

echo "<form>";
```

You can get $mail_id on backend with this code

```
$mail_reply_id = (!empty($_POST['reply'])) ? key($_POST['reply']) : 0;
$mail_delete_id = (!empty($_POST['delete'])) ? key($_POST['delete']) : 0;
```

Comment: Would you please explain how the code works especially this part `$mail_reply_id = (!empty($_POST['reply'])) ? key($_POST['reply']) : 0;
$mail_delete_id = (!empty($_POST['delete'])) ? key($_POST['delete']) : 0;`